# ip rule does not seem to be invoked

Tags: networking, iptables

I have two connections on my local machine, one is via eth0 (has a static IP, let it be 10.10.10.10), another is via ppp0 (has a dinamic IP, for example 10.20.30.40). Both have access to the Internet. I also have a remote server (let's assume it has IP 1.2.3.4) to which I want to connect from my local machine in such a way that packets having source address 10.10.10.10 (eth0) should go through eth0, while those having 10.20.30.40 (ppp0) as a source address should go through ppp0.

Preliminary I deleted ip rule for main route table in order to prevent packets being treated by this rule.

After that, I created two route tables, one for eth0 (named ETH) and another for ppp0 (named PPP). Then I added routes to these tables as follows:

```
ip route add default dev ppp0 table PPP
ip route add default dev eth0 table ETH
```

Then I added ip rules as followings:

```
ip rule add from 10.10.10.10 lookup ETH
ip rule add from 10.20.30.40 lookup PPP
```

And it doesn't work. However, when I use `ip rule add from all` instead of pointing to a specific IP it works (sure, packets go through only one interface in this case). So, it seems like ip rule is not invoked when I specify IP.

What could be a reason of such strange behavior?

Does anyone have ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason. 
The cause of this problem is a program (written with usage of QT QTcpSocket::bind()) that binds a socket with an appropriate interface, but not the routing settings. It does not do that properly for unknown reason. I tried using native linux socket functions and now it runs like clockwork.